# Gitlab - Author of commit

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a setup whereby multiple users can commit code from a single server. Each time you commit, you have to enter your login credentials to gitlab. The author of each commit comes under the name "dev team" which has been set in the git config.

My question: How do I find who made the commit, as in which credentials was used to make the commit.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can't. The credentials are only used to allow push to the server - they are not logged with git in any way.

Comment: This sounds like some kind of misuse of Git. Why aren’t you committing as yourselves, and why do you have to log in to commit? (Did you mean “push”?)

Comment: Please create separate local users for each person in the server(the machine where they modify and commit files) so that every one can log in with his/her own username. Then their local git repositories and git configs are separate from others. They can use their own `user.name` and `user.email` and credential. It's not safe for a number of persons to login as the same user in the server. One's credential could be easily leaked to another.

Comment: "We gave everyone the keys to the work truck. Last night, someone crashed it into a tree. Is there a way to find out who drove the truck into a tree?" Basically you've set yourself up to have to solve a crime here. If everyone has their own work truck, though, the solution will be much simpler. If a login were expensive (like a work truck), sharing it might still be worthwhile—but a login is *cheap*, as in, the price tends to be $0 or close to that.

Comment: Agreed with all the above comments. However, this is the setup that we somehow have to work with. Thank you for taking the time to confirm that it cant actually be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, its not good practice/ safe for multiple users to use the same login to connect to the server.

For adding multiple users to your project (using GitLab) please refer this [document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/).